# Powershell 7Zip Compression Can't Allocate Required Memory

Tags: powershell, memory, compression, 7zip

So I have a script that is supposed to take a backup of a database and the compress it into a zip file. I am using 7Zip and am getting the following:

```
Error: "Can't Allocate Required Memory"
```

when I try to compress the backup. The backup is roughly 2.3GBs and the remote machine that I am trying to run the script on has 3GB of memory available when I look at Task Manger. Also, when I open Powershell on the remote machine and run the code

```
set-alias sz "$env:C:\Temp\7-Zip\7z.exe"
sz a -t7z $zipfile $backup
```

that way it works just fine.

Here is my code:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {set-alias sz "$env:C:\Temp\7-Zip\7z.exe"}
Write-Host "Compressing Database and creating Zip file...."
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {sz a -t7z $zipfile $backup}
Write-Host "Completed Compressing Database and creating Zip file!"
```

I have looked at [a 7Zip forum post](https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/bugs/58/) and have tried to decrease the dictionary size, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Edit: The remote machine's Powershell version is 2.0 and is 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using powershell remoting to execute the script on the remote machine please have a read of this article [HERE](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory/)

As you will see the remote machines wsman service has some configurable limits on how much resources a script running via psremoting can consume.

To eliminate any wsman limits before changing them you could try run the script locally and interactively and see if it works. If you have access to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because you're running the 32-bit version of Powershell. To check, try:

```
[System.IntrPtr]::Size
```

If it's 4 - you're on the 32-bit Powershell.

Comment: The remote machine is running a 64-bit version of Powershell.